# #include doesn't show all the libraries when writing in C

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio Code, it is when I want to add a library in my code using the preprocessor keyword "#include" it doesn't show me all the available libraries only 2 local files.

When I fill in a package name and compile it, it doesn't show me any error.

[image: Doesn't show the available libraries]

I already have the -gcc compiler in my computer, at first when I was figuring out how to fix it I installed the Microsoft C/C++ extension but it didn't work well, then I went to search on Google if anyone had the same issue like me but it seems no one had the same problem.

[image: My extensions]
[image: Intellisense Configuration]

**Task.json:**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've fixed it by adding the option "C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath" in setting.json.

```
  "C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath": ["/usr/include", "${default}"].
```